# Smallest not existing number in two different columns in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Why doesn't the next Fiddle give me 102 ?
I'm looking for the smallest number that doesn't exist in both columns.

NOTICE: one column is a number, and the other is a varchar.

```
SELECT NVL(MIN(a1.id_int)+1, 111)
  FROM bPEOPLE a1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM PEOPLE a2
                    WHERE a2.id_int=a1.id_int+1
                   )
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                      FROM PEOPLE a3
                     WHERE TO_NUMBER(a3.id_str)=a1.id_int+1
                   )
   AND a1.id_int + 1 > 100
   AND a1.id_int + 1 < 110;
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9adff/1/0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your expression:

```
NVL(MIN(a1.id_int)+1, 111)
```

is only referencing the int column, in which the next value is 108.

You need to combine the two columns into a single column, then get the MIN:

```
SELECT  NVL(MIN(a.id_int)+1, 111) as next_id
FROM    (   SELECT id_int
            FROM PEOPLE
            UNION ALL
            SELECT TO_NUMBER(id_str) AS id_int
            FROM PEOPLE
        ) a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    PEOPLE b
            WHERE   a.id_int + 1 IN (b.id_int, TO_NUMBER(b.id_str))
        );
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9adff/44)**

Answer (score 1):

You doesn't get 102 because you start from the `id_int` column and then add `1`. You have to have 101 in `id_int` column in order to have a chance to get 102.

In other words, your error is, that you start with `MIN(a1.id_int)` and ignores `MIN(TO_NUMBER(a3.id_str))`.

Here is probably what you want

```
SELECT NVL(MIN(n)+1, 111) FROM
(
  SELECT id_int as n FROM PEOPLE
  UNION
  SELECT TO_NUMBER(id_str) as n FROM PEOPLE
) p
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      PEOPLE a2
    WHERE
      a2.id_int=n+1
  )
  AND
  NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT
        1
      FROM
        PEOPLE a3
      WHERE
        TO_NUMBER(a3.id_str)=n+1
    )
AND n + 1 > 100
AND n + 1 < 110;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's giving you the wrong result but I'm thinking you could create a union of the two columns and find the min that doesn't have a next one and add one to it

Try

```
SELECT MIN(t1.id)+1
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(id_str AS INT) id
    FROM people
    UNION
    SELECT id_int
    FROM people
) t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT CAST(id_str AS INT) id
    FROM people
    UNION
    SELECT id_int
    FROM people
) t2 ON t2.id = t1.id+1
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9adff/58)

Answer (score 0):

Your `not exists` clauses are saying "exclude rows where there is another row with a value one greater than the current row". The only row this is true for is the final row, whereas your question implies you want the first one.

To fix this, you just need to move the `+1` in your `not exists` clauses to the other colums in the predicates.

Also, in the fiddle, you're incrementing the integer value which holds 105. If you want to be incrementing 101, then you need to select the `id_str` column in your function.

```
SELECT
  NVL(MIN(a1.id_str)+1, 111)
FROM
  PEOPLE a1
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      PEOPLE a2
    WHERE
      a2.id_int+1=a1.id_int
  )
  AND
  NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT
        1
      FROM
        PEOPLE a3
      WHERE
        TO_NUMBER(a3.id_str)+1=a1.id_int
    )
AND a1.id_int + 1 > 100
AND a1.id_int + 1 < 110;
```

Finally, in the dataset provided you don't actually need to apply the `min` function, the (101, 105) row is the only one selected. You may still need to take the minimum with your real dataset however.